# how to export a specific category mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export, categories

so I have 8 category's with products and now I wanna build a website on a specific category I have in the big database 7500 products and I want to export only products with a specific category

database looks like this

```
id , productid, category, description, price, rating
```

and now I want to export only products from category 1
So I have to

```
SELECT category=2 from dbtable where rating=1
```

and then I want to export  .. this is not working .. I'm not good in to SQL .. so I need
advice - thank you !

Comment: How are you exporting? If you use `mysqldump`, you can use the `--where` option to specify which rows to export from the table.

Comment: please read [MY POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) about asking sql questions.. you need to provide more details here to get a good answer.. I don't really know what you are trying to do with your question as is.

Comment: @Barmar I export using phpmyadmin if u can tell me step by step how to .. please thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I don't know phpMyAdmin.

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: @ssnobody can u be more explicit please - thank you

Comment: wish I can know how to export .. if anyone can help - thank you

Comment: @JohnRuddell I explained it again SELECT category=2 from dbtable where rating=1 I want to export all products that has category = 2

Answer (score 1):

The single solution I found till now is this 
  MANUAL on PHPMyAdmin

Go to database select table > Search > Category LIKE 2 go down to options Number of rows per page to display 500 click on Go after that will result the first page with the 500 products , select all and click export - and I think i have to do this untill i finish to export all db

```
SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '2'
```

Comment: Use `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '2'` to export the results of that query.

Comment: @ssnobody I used your method and I get this  #1045 - Access denied for user 'dbtable'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Two thing could cause that error, 1) the mysql user doesn't have permission to write to /tmp (or whatever path you substituted.) If it's still /tmp, this is unlikely. Or 2) the dbtable user does not have the [`FILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) permission.

Answer (score 0):

why not just do

```
SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE category = 2 AND rating = 1;
```

that will get you all of the rows with category = 2

am I missing something or is that all you wanted??

Comment: SELECT * FROM `dbtable` WHERE `category` LIKE '%2%' will give me what i wanted .. after that I want to export that selection

Comment: well you have to run that query in a server side language like php and pull out the result and then do whatever it is you want to do with it.. theres a lot of helpful websites for that just search for it on google

Answer (score -1):

I also found some other solution to get that products if u have a bigger database and u need to exclude some categories ..
**be aware that before to back-up your database cos we will delete from database** 
here it is

```
DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '1';
DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '2';
DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '3';
DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '4';
DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '5';
DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '6';
DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category LIKE '7';
```

and u get result of category 8 only - my case :)

Comment: I'll agree that this is one way to remove data from a database, but I don't believe it's the best way to accomplish your task. As a note, you don't need a `LIKE` when you are testing a literal, so your query could have been `DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category = '1';`. In addition, you likely would have wanted to save some time and delete all except the one you want so you could have used `DELETE FROM dbtable WHERE category <> '2';`. Lastly, rather I'll mention that rather than exporting anything at all you've actually modified the table in place and deleted unwanted data.

Comment: Please note OP asks how to export data and not how to remove data.If OP executes all the 7 statements you post, there will be only one category (category 8) left in the database. The database owner/administrator will not be happy to find out all other 7 categories are missing.